# The Dirac-Hestenes equation as an eigenvalue equation: Interpretation of the $m \psi \gamma_0$ term and the wavevector

Tags: dirac-equation, clifford-algebra

This is somewhat of a follow-up question to my [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/766500/representing-the-dirac-equation-in-spacetime-algebra-without-leftover-indices/) on the Dirac-Hestenes equation. In that question, I asked whether the equation could be written in a form that omits the dangling indices.

### Context

In free space, using natural units, the Dirac-Hestenes equation takes the form
$$
\vec{\nabla} \psi I \sigma_3 = m \psi \gamma_0
$$
where $\psi$ is an even multivector field, $I\sigma_3$ is an arbitrarily chosen unit bivector, $m$ is the mass, and $\gamma_0$ is a future-pointing timelike unit vector. It's possible to remove one index by notating the unit bivector term as $\hat{B}$, resulting in the form
$$
\vec{\nabla} \psi \hat{B} = m \psi \gamma_0
$$
This leaves one final index, associated with $\gamma_0$.

### The realization

At the same time, I had another issue with $\gamma_0$: because the left side of the equation contains a spatial derivative, I expected that the right side should multiply $\psi$ with something that has *inverse* spacetime units, so I would expect to be written $\gamma^0$.

Then I remembered some basic relativistic physics:
$$
E^2 - p^2 = m^2
$$
Perhaps, when deriving the Dirac-Hestenes equation from the Klein-Gordon equation by taking the square root of the operators on both sides, *the intended square root on the right side is not simply a mass scalar, but the energy-momentum vector associated with the field.* For real particles, this energy-momentum vector is guaranteed to be timelike, and it would have the correct inverse spacetime units if interpreted as a wavevector $\vec{k}$. (However, it wouldn't necessarily be future pointing: perhaps corresponding to antiparticle states?)

I proposed that it was possible to write an index-free Dirac-Hestenes equation of the form
$$
\vec{\nabla} \psi \hat{B} = \vec{k} \psi
$$
This seemed to be the most compact form I could fit the equation into, and it seemed to suggest an interpretation of $\psi \mapsto \vec{\nabla} \psi \hat{B}$ as the momentum operator, with $\vec{k}$ being the associated eigenvalue.

## The problem

I've been told that such an equation could not be a valid equation of motion, as wavevectors arise from $\psi$, and not the other way around. Additionally, although the equation would admit planewave solutions in free space as its eigenstates, it would not admit a linear combination of planewaves generated from different wavevectors as a solution.

Perhaps the equation I derived is the relativistic equivalent to the time-independent Schrödinger equation, with eigenvalues being states with uniform energy-momentum distributions over spacetime. But at the same time, it seems like the Dirac-Hestenes equation could be be interpreted as the action of an operator with the resulting eigenvalue being $m \gamma_0$, and from a dimensional analysis perspective, $\vec{k}$ and $m \gamma_0$ seem to have equivalent units. The only major difference is that $\gamma_0$ can be chosen arbitrarily, whereas $\vec{k}$ depends on $\psi$.

### The question

So my question is: how are the wavevector $\vec{k}$ and the $m \gamma_0$ term related? Or equivalently, is the equation I have written meaningfully different from the Dirac-Hestenes equation as first presented?

Comment: In your attempt to avoid coördinates, you are actually just making mistakes. You seem to think that Hestenes himself would not have wanted to get rid of those index appearances. If you would check his textbooks, you would have realised that he is most interested in writing stuff in vector form without coördinates appearing. The form of the Dirac equation he gave you is just necessarily the way it is. $\gamma_0$ is coming from the observer's time direction. $I\sigma_3$ is coming from the observer's z-axis, which has to first be aligned. The equation is meaningful as it is.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector, with Dirac linearization or Dirac-Hestenes or...

Comment: i.e. the operator : $\hat{P}=\hbar \hat{K} $

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent what do you mean by "aligned" in reference to $I\sigma_3$? From my understanding, it shouldn't matter what spacelike bivector is part of the left side of the equation; the form of the wavefunction as it evolves over time can differ depending on the choice of bivector, but regardless of choice the wavefunctions evolve to identical states.

Also, I am aware of Hestenes's goals in reformulating the Dirac equation - I wouldn't be asking this question otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it does not matter which spacelike bivector is on the left side. However, it is extremely clear if you study the Wigner and Weyl classification of spins for QFT that the concept of spin half states require that we align our coördinate systems t,x,y,z axes everywhere in spacetime first. The choice of the spacelike bivector on the left then fixes the axis used to describe spin. It is customary to use the z axis, so it is $I\sigma_3$. The equation is therefore meaningful as it is.

Answer (score 0):

For your equation to make sense, you have to specify a couple of things:

- Specify how $\vec{k}$ is defined. For instance $$ \vec{k} =
      k^\mu\gamma_\mu $$
- Specify how $k^\mu$ transform under Lorentz
  transformation.
- Specify whether parameters $k^\mu$ are fundamental constants. And if they are not Lorentz scalar, how do you justify that fundamental constants are reference frame dependent?